# Only list name of EC2 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I set an a variable `$ec2-instance = GetEC2Instance` and this returns something like...

`GroupNames    : {}
Groups        : {}
Instances     : {somekey}
OwnerId       : 11111111
RequesterId   : 
ReservationId : r-111111111`

What I'm trying to do is list just the name of the EC2 instance. I know, "name" is a tag but not sure how to capture in PowerShell.

Comment: I think you mean `Get-EC2Instance` (Amazon Elastic Compute CLoud). Have a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Instance.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Get-EC2Instance` returns a list of Instances, you can iterate over that list and grab the value of the Name tag like this:

```
ForEach($i in (Get-EC2Instance).Instances) {
   ($i.Tags | ? { $_.Key -eq "Name"} | select -expand Value)
}
```